# What's the best place to appreciate Lantern Festival in Beijing?

Tags: china, public-holidays, beijing, festivals

Chinese New Year holiday comes to its climax with the Yuan Xiao (元宵节—yuán xiāo jié), or Lantern Festival and the next one will happen on the 19th February 2019.

Where is it best to see some good lantern displays on that day in Beijing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This site](http://www.beijingholiday.com/culture/lantern-festival.html) highlights where you can go:

> Qianmen Shang Yuan Lantern Party, Beijing Highlight: Lion dancing
>   performances
>
> The Lantern festival party in Qianmen is held to restore and expand
>   the original Shang Yuan Lantern Party which used to be held in
>   Beijing’s central Qianmen area in the Ming and Qing Dynasties.
>
> Featuring an exhibition of elegant handmade lanterns by craftsmen from
>   across the nation, the party will provide a festive gathering where
>   visitors can appreciate the art of traditional lanterns with modern
>   technology while enjoying riddles and fun games. Free of Charge!
>
> How to get there:  Many bus routes would take you there but the most
>   convenient way is to take the subway line 2 and get off at Qianmen
>   station.

Where you can see lantern displays:

> Now many other locations such as the Cultural Palace of Working People, Yuanmingyuan, or Winter Palace, and Zizhuyuan or Garden of Purple Bamboo also offer lamps show.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest going to any miaohui (庙会), which will be full of Chinese lanterns. You might have a tough time shopping there if you don't speak any Mandarin, though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer too, but I do find the answer from D Manokhin more comprehensive.